# Float right changing position of next element

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-position, css-float

I have a simple HTML, one parent div, and two children. When I am styling one child with `float` set to right, the next child goes up and the `margin-top` doesn't apply to it, which I don't want.

Here is the sample code.

```css
.inner1 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 5px solid red;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
<div class="inner1">

</div>
<div class="inner2">
Text that goes up after float.
</div>
</div>
```

Can someone please suggest how to handle this situation?

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Imadoddin/af1y7dkq/2/)

I want the output to be something like

[image]

Comment: can you provide the image how output you exactly want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```css
.outer{
        display:flex;
        flex-direction:column;
        align-items:flex-end;
      }
.inner1 {
         width: 50%;
         height: 100px;
         border: 5px solid red;
        }
.inner2{
       width: 50%;
  }
```

```html
<div class="outer">
<div class="inner1">

</div>
<div class="inner2">
Text that goes up after float.
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: How is this different from my second solution already posted?

Comment: Thanks, this is what I wanted.

Comment: @カメロン can't see your second solution sir

Comment: @Imad lol, it's literally snippet #2 which was added 5 mins before this answer was ever posted. If you looked, you'd find it.

Comment: @カメロン sorry bro. Don't take it personal. I appreciate your effort and upvoted already.

Comment: @Imad You're good. Not taking it personally either. Just think you would be confused/frustrated if the answer that was accepted was identical to yours and was posted 5 mins later. I'll delete my comments.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `float`. `float` is deprecated. Please take note of this solution using `flex`.

```css
.outer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row-reverse;
  align-items: center;
}
.inner1 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 5px solid red;
}

.inner2 {
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner1">

  </div>
  <div class="inner2">
    Text that goes up after float.
  </div>
</div>
```

Snippet #2

```css
.outer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
.inner1 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 5px solid red;
}

.inner2 {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner1">

  </div>
  <div class="inner2">
    Text that goes up after float.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But I want text to be below bordered div without changing width of it. Please see updated question with expected output

Comment: @Imad See snippet #2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `clear: both;` in the element what has `float: right;` property.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. It doesn't work this way. I had to apply it on different element.